# Magento 2 : How connect Magento with Neo4j Graphical Database

Tags: magento2, database, 3rd-party-library, database-connection

Does any one know how to connect Magento 2 with [Neo4j Graphical Database](https://neo4j.com/developer/php/) ?

There is a PHP client library (`composer require graphaware/neo4j-php-client:^4.0`) which i have updated in Magento project, resulted copied into the `vendor` directory.

Then i m trying to add following code which is not working properly.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:password@localhost:7687')
    ->build();
$query = "MATCH (n:Person)-[:FOLLOWS]->(friend) RETURN n.name, collect(friend) as friends";
$result = $client->run($query);

foreach ($result->getRecords() as $record) {
    echo sprintf('Person name is : %s and has %d number of friends', $record->value('name'), count($record->value('friends'));
}
```

Any other libraries are required to get it work it properly?

Comment: where did you add the code you posted? It lloks like you are not following magento-standards. that's why it's not working. also what does "not work" mean exactly? anny error? stacktrace?

Comment: @PhilippSander, sorry i was not aware of the magento-standards..i will update question with all require info. thanks